How does hololens perform camera calibration?
I want to perform the mr Three-position registration of hololens. I found that the camera calibration should be done before this.
How does Hololens calibrate the camera? By consulting the information, I learned that the depth camera should be called first, and the multi-angle checkerboard photos should be taken and imported into matlab to solve the internal and external parameters
At present, it is possible to call the depth camera in hololens, and hold down the volume button to take a screenshot. How to take checkerboard photos with depth camera?
Beginner's knowledge is limited, if possible, I hope to get more detailed steps to help me relieve the trouble.
Looking forward to the answer! thank you.
After calling the depth camera with hololens, I do not know how to shoot with the depth camera. Press the volume button at the same time to take a photo is not combined with multiple cameras, does not meet the regulations

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
